# DetailsView DropDownLists

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and currently having problem with dropdownlists in the DetailsView.

Exception error: System.InvalidOperationException: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

I have this code my code behind to refresh the list for the dropdownlists in DetailsView

```
protected void ddlVendor_SelectedIndexChanged 
               (object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    DropDownList ddlVendorBB = 
        (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("VendorBUName"); 

    if (ddlVendorBB != null) 
    { 
        Response.Write("SelectChanged"); 
        ddlVendorBB.DataBind(); 
    } 
} 

protected void SqlDataSourceProd_Selecting 
    (object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e) 
{ 
    DropDownList ddlVendor = 
        (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("VendorName"); 

    if (ddlVendor != null) 
    { 
        e.Command.Parameters["@VendorID"].Value = ddlVendor.SelectedValue; 
    } 
}
```

These two dropdownlists in the DetailsView

```
<EditItemTemplate> 
    <asp:DropDownList id="VendorName"
        datasourceid="VendorSqlDataSource"
        AutoPostBack="true"
        datatextfield="VendorName"
        DataValueField="VendorID"   
        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("VendorID") %>'  
        runat="server"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged" />

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="VendorSqlDataSource"
        ConnectionString="<%$Connectionstrings:ConnectionString%>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT VendorID, VendorName from MDF_Vendor"
        runat="server"> 
    </asp:SqlDataSource> 
</EditItemTemplate> 


<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList id="VendorBUName"
        datasourceid="VendorBUSqlDataSource" 
        datatextfield="VendorBUName"
        DataValueField="VendorBUID"   
        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("VendorBUID") %>'  
        runat="server"/>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="VendorBUSqlDataSource"
        runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$Connectionstrings:ConnectionString%>"
        selectcommand="SELECT VendorBUID, VendorBUName
                       from MDF_VendorBU
                       Where VendorID = @VendorID"
        OnSelecting="SqlDataSourceProd_Selecting"> 
        <SelectParameters> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="VendorID" Type="Int32" /> 
        </SelectParameters> 
    </asp:SqlDataSource> 
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Problem is:

If I leave SelectedValue= there, the dropdownlists in Edit mode seletected the correct value in the items listed when I first click Edit, but when I select a new VendorName, it errors "Databining method such as Eval(), Xpath(), and Bind()... ".

Now, if I removed the Selectedvalued for the dropdownlists, it will work for refreshing the VendorBUName when select a new VendorName, but NOT not selected the default VendorID when I click "Edit".  It just list the VendorName list without selected the current VendorID one.

Can someone please let me know what wrong in my codes?  Thanks!

Comment: Start by posting the full exception/error message.

Comment: I updated with the Full Exception error.  I am not sure what wrong my post.  I tried to format as much as possible already. Please look at the post again try to evaluate yours wording "you should be kind to", where is in the post that is not kind? Please... If you would like to help, then much much appreciated!

Comment: I reformatted your code to illustrate what I mean. You are free to rollback if you don't like it

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean now. In my notepad it was formatted correctly, but maybe when I pasted here, it wrapped the lines with long text.  Will pay attention next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you cannot use Bind where you are trying to use it. You should be able to use the [DataBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx) though

```
SelectedValue='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "VendorBUID") %>'
```

---

**Edit:** Since binding a value to the SelectedValue with DataBinder didn't work, you can try to set the value when binding data. Provided dataSource is some instance of a class that has a property called `VendorBUID`, something similar to this might work in

```
public override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    VendorBUName.DataBinding += dataBindDropDown;
}

private void dataBindDropDown(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    VendorBUName.SelectedValue = dataSource.VendorBUID;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Patrick, I get another error "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'VendorBUName' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items." Looks like it not page to find the value. (Sorry, I can not format in comment box here)

Comment: @Milacay: You might not be able to bind SelectedValue like that after all.. Hm.. What are you trying to accomplish by setting selectedvalue?

Comment: This is a DetailsView, so when I click Edit, the field VendorName and VendorBUName change to dropdownlist, the SelectedValue will selected the current VendorID and VendorBUID in the listed items.  If I remove the SelectedValue, it will not select the correct value when I click Edit.

Comment: I commented the line in my code behind like this "//ddlVendorBB.DataBind();" and the error goes away, but I am not able to refresh the 2nd dropdownlist (VendorBUName).  Any suggestion to modify the code behide to bind with whatever SelectedValue from VendorName?  Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to set SelectedValue when you databind `VendorBUName`. Subscribe to the event with `VendorBUName.DataBinding += databindVendor;` and in that method do `VendorBUName.SelectedValue = VendorBUID;`.

Comment: Sorry, I am lost. If you can please help me modify the code behind I posted originally.  thanks